# C++, Qt 4 Sqlite: can't create table

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, qt4

I'm trying to use sqlite as database for a symbian app but I can't create a table. Here's the code:

```
bool DatabaseManager::createExpenseTable(){

    if(QFile::exists(dbName)){
        this->showDebugMsg("Database file exist");
    }else{
        this->showDebugMsg("Database file exist DOES NOT exist");
    }

    // Create table "person"
    bool ret = false;
    if (db.isOpen()){
        this->showDebugMsg("Database open");
        QSqlQuery query;
        ret = query.exec("create table expense "
                  "(id int primary key, "
                  "item varchar(100)");
                  //"price double, "
                  //"date datetime)");

    }else{
        this->showDebugMsg("Database CLOSED");
    }
    if(ret){
       this->showDebugMsg("Table created");
    }else{
        this->showDebugMsg("Table NOT created");

    }
    return ret;
    }
```

As far as I can see from the debug messages "Database file exist" and "Database open" the database exists and is open.

But I always get the "table NOT created" message. Does any of you see where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait, I found the problem. with this code:

```
this->showDebugMsg(query.lastError().text());
```

I saw that "the table expense already exist" and so, it doesn't create a new one. sorry for bothering you all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a closing parenthesis missing in your query (you commented it out).

Comment: It's closed. Look just before the commented part. And byt the way, if they weren't close the code  wouldn't compile.

Comment: The parenthesis is missing in the quoted SQL!

Comment: @Segolas: It's not closed. hmn is right. You have commented out the code containing the closing parens. Removing the quotes and coalescing the strings shows that the code you posted executes this query: `create table expense (id int primary key, item varchar(100)` which is missing the last parens. And the code would compile even if you replaced the query by `kjrfhiherfhdfgvjhfgvjh` since the compiler has no way to guess whether what you're passing to the SQL driver is valid SQL - or, for that matter, it doesn't even know it's SQL. It just passes whatever bytes you told it to the SQL driver.